# Loop through all cells in a Excel Column to the end

Tags: c#, excel

Probably simple once i see the correct code but what is the best way to loop through a specific column in a worksheet until the end?

Comment: Until the end of what? The worksheet, the data area, or the current continuous chunck of data?

Comment: ya i guess i could have been more specific. To the end of current continuous data.

Comment: clarify _how_, not only what you want to implement. Using C#? Using VBA? Using Excel directly?
As much information you provide, as better. Otherwise you'll receive lots of answers that doesn't fit your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Just create a range object that points to the range you want to start at, then loop through each offset from that range until you get to a blank cell.

```
int i = 0;

while (target_range.Offset(i, 0).Value != "")
{
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Ya thought it would be pretty easy once i seen the code. Thanks for your help. I was trying to to do it using a [row,column] which wasn't working out for me. Never thought of starting with a cell then trying to navigate (offset) from that cell.